# How to Evaluate $\int_0^n \frac{e^{ax}}{1+ce^{bx}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate $$\int_0^n \frac{e^{ax}}{1+ce^{bx}}dx,$$ where $a,b,c$ are constants.

***After Suggestion/comment given below:***

$u=ce^{bx}$ this would covert above integral to following

$$ \bigg(\frac{1}{c}\bigg)^{a/b}\bigg(\frac{1}{b}\bigg)\int_{t_1}^{t_2} u^{a/b-1}(1+u)^{-1}du$$ where $t_1=c,t_2=ce^{bn}$

I can expand $1/(1+u)$ as geometric series assuming $|u|<1$, but that wont give simple answer.

Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: Are you aware of the gaussian hypergeometric function ?

Comment: I can give you a hint that you can apply $u$ substitution of $ce^{bx}$

Comment: @MathGenius That really helps. Now I am stuck with final integral which look like Beta type integral but with different limits. Lets see...

Comment: suppose $a<0,b>0$ what would be the approach?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I wasn't aware about that and not sure how to use it. I used second comment and came up with second integral

Comment: You can easily express it in terms of the incomplete Beta function through $u\mapsto-u$.

Comment: Found a way to get solution using Wolfram site: https://www.wolframalpha.com/  Enter: Integrate[exp(a*x)/(1+c*exp(b*x)),x]